# A memory with 32 address bits and 16 data bits has the capacity of?

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu-architecture

a) 2G
b) 16G
c) 32 G
d) 64G

So I found my answer to be 8G. But according to the teacher it is d) 64 G. Can someone explain this?

I thought it’s 2^32 * 2 since there are 2 bytes per address, and then divide that by 2^30, because 2^30 bytes is 1 GB ?

Comment: Sorry what is the difference between GiB and GB ? I always thought 10^9 is just an approximation of 2^30, and GiB and GB are Gigabytes

Comment: Underspecified: we don't know what the addressable unit of storage is. "16 bits" could just mean that there is a 16 bit data bus.  If 32 bit words are addressable, then it takes two transfers to load and store a word.

Comment: "can someone explain this", why doesn't your teacher do? Tricking the students, and not explaining anything, must be a really bad one; nitpicking, you could even say all his answer are wrong, for he's not giving any units. 64G ... 64G what ? words? grams? bits? meter? bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64 giga**bits** (Gib) = 8 giga**bytes** (GiB).

The problem is that none of the answers have units, only prefixes, so they're both right for a reasonable choice of unit.

Apparently since the bus width was given in bits, they want the memory capacity in bits.  That makes some sense, but I'd still say the question is ambiguous and a trick question.

It's also ambiguous to me because they haven't told you whether each byte has its own address, or whether it's word-addressable only.  (**We only know from the correct answer being 64 Gib that it's word-addressable**).  Modern CPUs other than some DSPs almost all use byte-addressable memory, even if (like early DEC Alpha) they don't support loads narrower than a word.  As @Kaz points out, it could be a word-addressable machine with 32-bit words where a word takes 2 bus cycles to transfer, **so the question is under-specified even for finding the capacity in bits.**

---

And if you're going to be technical about units, 1 GB is 10^9 bytes, while 1 GiB is 2^30 bytes in SI units.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte.

(Many people and lots of software don't bother with SI units, though, and use GB even for power-of-2 cases where they mean 2^30.  SI's attempt to resolve the ambiguity hasn't fully caught on, perhaps because SI power-of-2 naming is ridiculous to say out loud.  I've never heard anyone say or even type out "gibibyte" un-ironically without at least mocking the name, only use the abbreviations to be completely un-ambiguous that they mean power-of-2 units.)

Note that hard-drive vendors definitely mean power-of-10 GB or TB for hard-drive sizes, so they can put a larger number on the sticker, but 4GB of DRAM is definitely 4 GiB because RAM is naturally power-of-2 based.

---

Technically you don't know the size of a byte on the machine, so really you could only say 8 giga-octets (or 64 Gib).  Machines with 9-bit bytes and other sizes other than 8 used to exist, but IDK if anyone's ever claimed their machine had 16-bit bytes instead of calling it a word-addressable machine like everyone else would.  So this is not a real ambiguity unless you're purposely being weird.

Comment: Sorry what is the difference between GiB and GB ? I always thought 10^9 is just an approximation of 2^30, and GiB and GB are Gigabytes

Comment: @AznBoyStride: Sometimes people use GB for 2^30, but SI defined Gi / Mi / ki prefixes to resolve the ambiguity.  Updated my answer with a link.  You can also google on `gib vs gb` for more stuff.

Comment: You might want to point out that the whole GiB/GB 2^30 vs 10^9 is essentially a vim-vs-emacs or pepsi-vs-coke style holy war thing and not really a "fact" as you point out (I'm on the "let's use XiB for 2^X side, BTW). Your "SI defined Gi / Mi / ki prefixes to resolve the ambiguity" is a bit deceptive :). I read it as "there was this ambiguity but then SI resolved it", but the truth is that the SI units were _always_ like that and made no particular decision on this matter, and people just use the existing SI names as one of the arguments for GiB style.

Comment: In class, you should stick to whatever convention your teacher uses, certainly on exams which are no place to argue minutiae like this. In a multiple-choice test it's not likely to be a problem because using the wrong style probably won't change your answer enough to be closer to another option (and the fact you aren't getting the exact answer should be a hint that you're "doing it wrong" at least with respect to the conventions for your class).

Comment: It seems that it was a trick question because the teacher intentionally left out "8G". But it's a bad question because (hopefully) no one uses the unit "G" in the real world.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yup, good point.  Added a section for that, and another section to point out that if you want to really split hairs, you could possibly get away with describing this machine as having 16-bit bytes instead of being word-addressable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad question, if nothing else.

It doesn't matter what the size of the of a 'word', or the number of data bits is.  The address bus is - quite literally - 32 wires that can each be a 1 or a 0.  That means the number of addresses is 2^32, or roughly 4 billion |(which we call 4G)

16 data bits is two bytes per address, so one could argue the 'total size of the memory' is 8 GB.  That is the same as 64 gigabits, since 8 its per byte.

Trick question.